# Can "meet her" be pronounced [miːdər] in American English?

Tags: pronunciation, flapping

I heard people say *meet her* as  [miːdər] in an American movie.

Is it ok to pronounce it like that, or am I mishearing?

Comment: It's not a /d/, it's an [alveolar flap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_flap), which sounds a lot like a /d/. But aside from that quibble, it's a very common pronunciation of *"meet her"*.

Comment: @Peter has the right of it; in American English, _meet her_ is indistuishable from _meter_, and rhymes with _leader_.